# Pick m of n: how many are unique?

Tags: probability, statistics

I'm a bit embarrassed to ask this here, but I'm not very good at statistics and curious about the right answer.

If I pick $m$ elements out of $n$ randomly ($m<n$), the right way to do it is to shuffle my $n$ elements and take the first $m$.

But if I do it "wrong" by just picking a random element out of the $n$ for $m$ times, putting back always, how many unique elements can I expect to get after $m$ draws?

Writing this down makes it really sound like a high school question. And that is probably what it is.

The first draw is always unique. The second draw has a chance of $1/n$ to be unique, the next one $2/n$ and so on.

But given $n$ and $m$, is there a closed formula for picking $m$ times from $n$ – how many unique picks do I expect?

Answer (score 1):

First you say, "If I pick $m$ elements out of $n$ randomly $(m < n),$ the right way to do it is to shuffle my $n$ elements and take the first $m.$ That amounts to sampling *without replacement*. Using that method, there is no way to get the same element more than once. With that method are ${n \choose m} = \frac{n!}{m!(n-m)!}$ different samples of size $m$. If you have $n = 3$ elements A, B, and C, and you are choosing $n = 2,$ then the possible samples are:

```
AB AC BC
```

If you keep track of the order then there are six *ordered* samples without replacement:

```
AB AC BC BA, CA, CB
```

Then you say, "But if I do it 'wrong by just picking a random element out of the $n$ for $m$ times, putting back always, how many unique elements can I expect to get after $m$ draws?"  Now your are sampling *with replacement,* but there is
also an implied order. (Pick the first, replace; pick the second, replace; and so on.) As you say, there is a possibility of choosing the
same element more than once. There are $n^m$ possible ordered samples when choosing with replacement. In our example,

```
AA  AB  AC
BA  BB  BC
CA  CB  CC
```

Your main question has to do with the chances of picking the same element
more than once, when sampling with replacement. This is essentially the famous 'birthday problem': You have 25 people
is a room, each with an equal chance of having been born on any of 365 days
(ignore leap years). What is the probability of getting a birthday match?
The probability of no match is:

$$P(\text{No Match}) = \frac{365}{365}\frac{364}{365}\frac{363}{365} \cdots
\frac{365-(25-1)}{365} = \prod_{i=0}^{24}\left(1 - \frac{i}{365}\right) = \frac{{}_{365}P_{25}}{365^{25}} = 0.4313.$$

So there is more than a 50:50 chance of a least one birthday match among
the people in the room. Here the symbol ${}_{365}P_{25}$ is called
the 'permutations of 365 objects taken 25 at a time' ${}_{n}P_{m} = \frac{n!}{(n-m)!}.$ ('Permutations' are ordered samples.)

There are several dozen posts on this site dealing with the birthday problem
and variations of it. You can search among them for whatever details interest you.